# What the simplest way to sub-query a variable number of rows into fields of the parent query?

Tags: sql

What the simplest way to sub-query a variable number of rows into fields of the parent query?

```
PeopleTBL
   NameID int - unique
   Name   varchar

Data: 1,joe
      2,frank
      3,sam
```

---

```
HobbyTBL
   HobbyID   int - unique
   HobbyName varchar

Data: 1,skiing
      2,swimming
```

---

```
HobbiesTBL
    NameID  int
    HobbyID int

Data: 1,1
      2,1
      2,2
```

---

The app defines 0-2 Hobbies per NameID.

What the simplest way to query the Hobbies into fields retrieved with "Select * from PeopleTBL"

Result desired based on above data:

```
NameID  Name    Hobby1  Hobby2  
1        joe     skiing
2        frank   skiing  swimming
3        sam
```

Comment: I am not aware of any way to do this, and there are good reasons for this.  In general it is not a good idea to have an arbitrary number of columns, because how do you process them?  What happens if you have 1000 hobbies? 0?  Do you have an actual requirement? (Actually there may be a way to do this, but it is pretty horrible, and I haven't though it through).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but if you want to fetch all the hobbies for a person in one row, the following query might be useful (MySQL):

```
SELECT NameID, Name, GROUP_CONCAT(HobbyName) AS Hobbies
FROM PeopleTBL
JOIN HobbiesTBL USING NameID
JOIN HobbyTBL USING HobbyID
```

Hobbies column will contain all hobbies of a person separated by `,`.
See documentation for [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for details.

I don't know what engine are you using, so I've provided an example with MySQL (I don't know what other sql engines support this).

Comment: I need the rows in columns, not concatenated into one column. MS sqlserver would use Pivot but I'd prefer a generic sql that is more likely to work across more sql variants.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select P.NameId, P.Name
    , Min( Case When H2.HobbyId = 1 Then H.HobbyName End ) As Hobby1
    , Min( Case When H2.HobbyId = 2 Then H.HobbyName End ) As Hobby2
From HobbyTbl As H
    Join HobbiesTbl As H2
        On H2.HobbyId = H.HobbyId
    Join PeopleTbl As P
        On P.NameId = H2.NameId
Group By P.NameId, P.Name
```

What you are seeking is called a crosstab query. As long as the columns are static, you can use the above solution. However, if you want to dynamic build the columns, you need to build the SQL statement in middle-tier code or use a reporting tool.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for something more succinct like pivot. (There are 100's of Hobbies and three other mapping tables with many unique ID's, approx 600 fields when cross-tabulated)

Comment: @joe - PIVOT is SQL Server specific and IMO, more verbose than the above approach.

Comment: @joe - BTW, if you have 600 some odd columns, then I would build that in code.

Comment: ...or question if this really is the best way of representing/presenting the data :)